# Remove all web sites data

Tags: safari, history, browser-cache

Does the "Remove all websites data" in Preferences → Privacy on Safari 5.1.7 remove them only from Safari or all other browsers installed on the computer?

I get a warning:

> Are you sure you want to remove all website data **on your computer**

before I can confirm. I'm currently using Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

Every browser has its own history files (in a directory in C:\USERS\username), so Safari will only remove its own data. When it says "on your computer", it assumes it's the only browser present - which is probably the case on the majority Macs. Safari should know though that, in a Windows installation, Internet Explorer will **always** be present.

Comment: So is there any risk on the IE or other browsers' files??

Comment: No risk at all. Every browser has its own directory(s) in the user directory. Search for "Safari" under c:\user\username and you'll find them. They should be in the Local and/or Roaming subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

The commands to clear cache and other user files from inside a specific browser, naturally only delete files from that specific browser.

If you want to perform a more in-depth cleaning, I suggest you to use a tool like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) or something similar.

Comment: I don't want to clear the other browsers I'm just afraid this what could have happened.. Any thing specific on Safari 5.1.7 ??